# slope deflections method analysis of beam

Tags: structural-engineering

why we need to consider 2 conditions , the beam curve downwards ( as in 11-3) and beam curve upwards ( as in 11-4) ?
What's the difference between 2 cases ?

I notice that in both cases , the author assume clockwise as positive
here are the 3 consecutive pages of notes

I think the second cases where the curve curve upwards is unnecessary because we can see that the curve curve downwards (U shape) in the first photos .
[image: hh]
[image: cc]
[image: dgr]

***EDIT : ONE more question here , why for the relative linear dispalcement , we only need to displace B relative to A ? We dont have to displace A relative to B ?***

Comment: One situation is if A is fixed, the other is if B was fixed.  I don't understand the question here; the book explains the situation.

Comment: In the second case( figure 11-4)  , why will the curve curve upwards ? Can it  curve downwards (U-shape) just like in the first case (figure 11-3) ?

Answer (score 2):

You should really try to read the book more carefully, it clearly explains what's going on.

This method calculates the effect of each degree of freedom: what happens when you rotate A (and only A, so B stays fixed)? What happens when you rotate B (and A stays fixed)? What happens when you impose a deflection at one of the supports (but not the other)?

To calculate these effects, the rotations are all applied clockwise. $\theta_A$ is a clockwise rotation around A, which causes the beam to deflect downwards. $\theta_B$ is a clockwise rotation around B, which causes the beam to deflect upwards.

Since this method is for arbitrary loads, you don't know if $\theta_A$, $\theta_B$ or $\Delta$ will be positive or negative. But by calculating the forces generated by each of them, you can solve for the entire structure. With the generic loading shown in Figure 11-2 it looks like $\theta_A > 0$, $\theta_B < 0$ and $\Delta > 0$, but there's no way to mathematically know that for any load pattern until you do the work.

Regarding why $\Delta$ is only calculated for node B, again: read the book. Here, I'll transcribe it for you:

> If far the far node B of the member is displaced relative to A, so that the cord of the member rotates clockwise (positive displacement) and yet both ends do not rotate, then **equal but opposite** moment and shear reactions are developed in the member [...]

So, who cares whether it was A or B that got displaced? The result is the same! That's why they only did it for B, they'd just be repeating themselves if they did it for both nodes.

Thank you for finally posting a question about a concept instead of a specific exercise, but next time please try reading the concept ***carefully*** before asking.

Comment: Do you mean we can choose either the applied rotation is clockwise or anticlockwise ? If we choose clockwise , then we have to keep the applied moment at 2 ends clockwise and vice versa ? We cant apply the moment at one end is clockwise , another end is counter clockwise ?

Comment: This is the derivation of a method. So you need to choose your sign convention: are bending moments and rotations positive clockwise or counter-clockwise? Are deflections positive downwards or upwards? So long as you are consistent, you can do whatever you want. So yeah, if you want you can make rotations positive counter-clockwise, but then that will affect your equations (they will be equal but opposite to the solution given in the book). But that also means that no, you can't apply clockwise on A and counter-clockwise on B because then you aren't being consistent.

Comment: ok , why do we need to apply moment at 2 ends ? in real situation , we wouldnt notice the beam curve upwards ( just like figure 11-4) , am i right ? In figure 11-2 , i could only notice the beam curve downwards

Comment: But what if the applied load was upwards, not downwards? Forget about Figure 11-2, it represents a generic beam of any type, of any length, with any load imaginable. To repeat myself: **This is the derivation of a method**. It doesn't care about the specifics of your problem, but is a way to solve ***any*** problem. So yeah, in Figure 11-2 you don't see the second support rotating upwards, but downwards. That just means that the results found for that support will be negative. And that's just fine.

Comment: do you mean for the case in figure 11-4 , we assume the applied load was upwards ? so , in real life , we dont have to consider the case in 11-4 if the load is applied downwards ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks, do you have the slightest clue what is being discussed in this chapter of the book? It really doesn't seem like you do. This has absolutely nothing to do with applying forces. ***You are applying displacements and rotations*** and then calculating the resultant internal forces. Once you know how much force is applied for a unit displacement, you can then calculate how much force is generated by the actual applied loads, but that comes later. This has nothing to do with the loads applied on the structure. To repeat myself in other questions: go back to the start of the book.

Comment: so , why we have to apply the moment at both ends , at A , and at B ? Why we cant just apply moment at A only ?

Comment: I'm getting frustrated just reading these comments...  You still have to consider that case, it is part of the derivation to assume that the moment is acting clockwise on B due to the sign convention they established.  If the real situation has something else, this will be reflected by negative values.  It doesn't mean you can ignore what is happening there.

Comment: @kelvinmacks: That's a reasonable question. You'll notice that the results for $\theta_A$ and $\theta_B$ are inverted. The value of $M_{AB}$ with $\theta_A$ is equal to the value of $M_{BA}$ with $\theta_B$. The author could have merely said that, but they preferred to show it. The difference being that the values of $M_{AB}$ and $M_{BA}$ are different for the same $\theta$, while they are equal for the same $\Delta$.

Comment: @JMac , why we need to consider the  moment is acting clockwise on B ???? What does it mean ? Does it mean we need to consider it when the load ia applied upwards at B ?

Comment: @Wasabi ,just like the case in $\Delta$ , no matter which part the moment is applied , the results would still be the same , why we have to consider the case where the moment is applied at B  for angular displacement?

Comment: @kelvinmacks: That's not true. When the rotation is on A, $M_{AB} = \dfrac{4EI}{L}\theta$ and $M_{BA} = \dfrac{2EI}{L}\theta$. When the rotation is on B, $M_{AB} = \dfrac{2EI}{L}\theta$ and $M_{BA} = \dfrac{4EI}{L}\theta$. These results are different. They are the same in terms of "the moment for the node that was rotated is always $\dfrac{4EI}{L}\theta$ and the other is $\dfrac{2EI}{L}\theta$", but the values of $M_{AB}$ and of $M_{BA}$ change depending on where the rotation occurs. With $\Delta$, it doesn't matter where it occurs, the values of $M_{AB}$ and $M_{BA}$ will always be equal.

Comment: So , due to the differences in $M_(AB)$ and $M_(BA)$ , we have to consider the case differently , namely , we should consider the case where the moment is applied at both ends ?

Comment: @kelvinmacks: As to what you asked JMac, I really hope he doesn't answer because he shouldn't have to. I have already answered that question both in my answer and in a comment here. If you are incapable of seeing that, then you really, *really*, **really**, ***really*** need to stop asking questions here (temporarily) and go talk to your teacher. You've already asked 32 questions on this site, all but 6 of which received answers, only one of which you accepted. I think it's clear that this site's format isn't working very well for you and I honestly suggest you go see your teacher.

Comment: @Wasabi , for the question / answer / comment that i have stopped repyling , tat means i accepted and understand the answer already . I just forgt to choose the accepted answer sometimes . Really , i enjoy using this platform and learnt a lot of things that i cant learn in the classroom . This is because my lecturer doesnt teach and go into so details of the knowldege

Comment: @Wasabi , regrading the $\Delta$ part , since no matter we displace the member at A or B , the results is the same , then why we dont have to take both? I mean MAB + MBA = -12EI /( L^2) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51774/discussion-between-kelvinmacks-and-wasabi).